# Avoiding a for loop in Matlab with Kronecker product

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sequence

If I have two sequences A and B containing the elements a1, a2, ... and b1,b2, ... where a_i and b_i are of dimension 1xn and 1xm, respectively, then I want to make a new sequence C which contains: a_i(1)*b_i, a_i(2)*b_i, ... , a_i(n)*b_i. So for the ith element of C, I want to have the Kronecker product of the elements a_i and b_i. I want to code this in Matlab, but without a for-loop. For the case when b_i are scalars, the desired result is achieved with

```
C = A.*B
```

However, this does not work for non-scalar b_i's. So what I do now is for sequences of length L:

```
C = [];
for ii = 1:L
    C = [C; kron(A(ii,:),B(ii,:))];
end
```

But I have the idea that this must be possible without a for loop. Here is my code using the symbolic toolbox:

```
clc; clear;

L = 5;

syms('a1',[L,1]);
syms('a2',[L,1]);
syms('b1',[L,1]);
syms('b2',[L,1]);

A = [a1,a2];
B = [b1,b2];

C1 = A.*B % only for size(B,2)=1

C2 = [];

for ii = 1:L
    C2 = [C2;kron(A(ii,:),B(ii,:))];
end
C2

C3 = kron(A,B) % does not work
```

Comment: Just to be clear: For loops are not slow in MATLAB since 5 years ago, at least. There is no practical reason (aside from style) to avoid them anymore. What is slow, is that you have not preallocated `C2` and it increases sizes each loop.

Comment: `syms` is also slow if you don't need it, it's unclear why the symbolic toolbox is required here,  a simple numerical example would help

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ah, I didn't know that! The not preallocated `C2` was for the sake of the example, just as the `syms` (@Wolfie). In my 'real' script, I used the preallocation and some additional operations around it. Thanks for the info anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) are used to compute the result:

```
C = reshape(B .* reshape (A, L, 1, []), L, []);
```

Comment: In the first place this looked like the correct solution, however, for higher dimensions this mixes stuff up...

Comment: @seaver I answered the _text_ of your question. Probably you have more questions in _mind_ about higher dimensions ?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear, higher dimensions might not be the best term :P. I mean, for size(A,2)>1 and size(B,2)>1 (for example 2 and 4 respectively), your output is not equivalent with the output of the for-loop and Kronecker function. I'm not sure how...

Comment: You can try that [online](https://rextester.com/HYQDT70581) comparing both methods. I cannot see a difference.

Comment: Then I guess there is a problem with the length L: [code](https://rextester.com/AYUVD28254)

Comment: I am using `sum(CC(:)-C(:))` that in all cases gives small numbers like `-3.9968e-15`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224727/discussion-between-seaver-and-rahnema1).

Comment: Kronecker product is not point-wise product. So either the question didn't put it correctly, or...

Comment: ... they can produce the same result!